# phpstorm next-line braces

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

I recently started using PHPStorm. Now I have a simple question but I cant find the answer.

So, I want that the braces of funtions, classes etc. go automatically in the next line, like:

```
function xyz(){  
}
```

will be

```
function xyz()  
{  
}
```

without pressing CTRL + ALT + L all the time. Is there a way to do it?
I appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want the setting (this is the way to get there on OSX at least):

- Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP

  - Tab: Wrapping and Braces
  - Braces placement

    - Other: Next line

Comment: And should be the default, but for sure you have to type the "\n" after `function whatever()`

Comment: @PhilippDahse I guess that depends on the scheme you select, it is not default on my installation.

Comment: @jeroen Thats what I already have. Still when I write    function xyz(){  the { wont move in the next line without moving the coursor before it and hitting enter

Comment: @Mon0ncle Hmmmm, it works with the auto-generated methods which I use a lot but I don't know about typing...

Comment: @Mon0ncle Use `Code | Reformat Code` and it will format it to your code style. As for *"Still when I write function xyz(){"* -- how do you write it exactly? Typing all characters? In such case it will not move it to then new line automatically. Why not use Live Template (code snippets)? It will write such stuff in desired style.

Comment: @LazyOne Its hard to explain what I mean since I am not a native english speaker. Ok, I try. I am looking for a "auto correct" feature. Like when you write "Helo" on your phone it will automatically replace it with "Hello".  
So when I write every single letter of "function xyz(){}" and my coursor is between the braces I want the braces to switch to next-line.   
Im sorry this sounds a bit strange but im really new to PHPstorm and I dont have any clue about Live-Templates etc.

Comment: @Mon0ncle https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm